# What is a good mathematical definition for a bottleneck?

Tags: geometry

What would precisely capture the intuition of a "bottleneck"?
[image]

Comment: Could you give us a little bit more context?  What kind of answer are you looking for?  What kind of mathematical object should have the "bottleneck property"?  Is it a region in the plane, perhaps?

Comment: I guess one definition might be the amount of "fluid per second" one can put through the thing. But that kinda misses the idea that a bottleneck is a part of the object. Maybe if one considers the number of unit thickness tubes one can put through the thing and then declare the bottleneck to be the set of points that if moved appropriately but little would allow us to put more tubes through?

Comment: It seems to me that bottleneck depends on context.  Consider a pipe that can carry 10 liters per minute with a narrow constriction that can carry only 1 L/m. If the total flow through the pipe is no more than 1l/m, the constriction is not a bottleneck. It only becomes a bottleneck if the inflow exceeds 1l/m.

Comment: @MJD: I think we could qualify that as the distinction between a potential bottleneck and an active bottleneck, and in the context of flow networks, that would not really present much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be useful to abstract the problem a bit.  To deal with the *geometric* idea of a bottleneck will be very complex, because fluid flow is geometrically very complex.  To take a super-simple example, consider:

[image: two simple flow examples]]

Each part of the pipe on the left is at least as wide as the corresponding part of the pipe on the right, but the pipe on the right might have better flow-through properties, not because it's narrower, but because the shape is important.  (My idea is that the sudden change of width on the left might cause some sort of turbulent backflow that is not present on the right.)

Let's try to break the problem in two: first, we would like to find an description of the geometric situation that erases many microscopic details, such as whether the inside walls are smooth or rough.  Let's imagine that the geometric situation is simple enough and regular enough that we can replace it with an abstract description: instead of the pictures above, we might have:

[image: ![abstract description]

This means that in the left picture we have a pipe with a capacity of 3 (liters per minute, or whatever) feeding into a pipe with a capacity of only 1, and on the right we have the same pipe with capacity 3 feeding into a pipe with a capacity of 2.  An abstract view of a pipe system might be a network of lines like this, each annotated with its capacity.  The picture in your original question might be abstracted as something like this:

[image]

There is a wide section, with a capacity of 3.4 units, and then a narrow section, with a capacity of 1.0 units, and then a wide section again, with a capacity of 3.3 units.

To see how this abstract view might shed some light on the notion of a bottleneck, let's consider this simple abstract network:

[image]

Here we're considering the flow from *s* to *t*, which can go via either *a* or by *b*.  The maximum possible flow from *s* to *t* is 4, with 2 flowing via *a* and 2 flowing via *b*.    We can identify the pipe from *b* to *t* as a bottleneck because if it were bigger, the total maximum flow 
from *s* to *t* would be increased from 4 to 5.  If we want to increase flow from *s* to *t*, and we can only make one pipe bigger, the *b*–*t* pipe is clearly the place to do it.  In contrast, the pipes from *s* to *b* and from *a* to *t* are not bottlenecks in this sense, because making them bigger will not increase the total flow from *s* to *t*.

In this view a bottleneck is a single pipe which, if enlarged, would increase the total flow throw the network.  This makes sense if we consider the abstraction of the example you posted in your question:

[image]

Here the maximum total flow from left to right is only 1 unit.  But if the narrower middle section were enlarged, the flow could be increased to 3.3.  So under this definition, we could consider the middle section to be a bottleneck, but not the outer sections.  I think this is reasonable.

I think this is a helpful way to think about the issue.  Another insight it might give us is that there are different scales at which bottlenecks can operate.  Consider the diamond-shaped network from earlier.  In this network neither *s*–*a* nor *a*–*t* is by itself a bottleneck: both are operating at capacity, and increasing either one alone won't improve the total flow from *s* to *t*.  But operating *together* they could be considered a bottleneck, since if we increased the total size of the pipe from *s* to *a* to *t*, the total flow would be greater.

Or we can imagine the diamond network above embedded in a larger network:

[image]

Before, the capacity-2 pipe from *b* to *t* was a bottleneck.  But in the context of this larger network, it isn't; increasing it from 2 to 3 won't improve the total flow through the network.

I think that if there is a sticking point here, it will be converting the geometric network to an abstract one, but that if this can be done, the abstract view will be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function $A(s,d)$ which given a shape s and a distance $d$, indicates the area of the slice through $s$ that is $d$ units of distance from the start.

Then locations $d$ where

$\frac{\partial A}{\partial d} < 0$

Are regions of compression (i.e. The tube is getting smaller),

And triples (a,b,c) such that

$$A(s,a) , A(s,c) < A(s,b)$$

Indicate there exists a bottle neck between $a,c$.

Comment: The dimensions on the left and right of your inequality don't match, so the result of the comparison will depend on an arbitrary choice of units for measuring$A$. For example, a shape might be a bottleneck under this definition if $A$ is measured in square meters, but the same shape might no longer be a bottleneck if measured in square meters instead. You might use $$A_s(a)A_s(c) < (A_s(b))^2$$ to fix this problem.

Comment: Also I think the < should be >.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends quite a bit on context.  In flow networks (let's say, directed graphs where the edges have capacities), I *might* define it as a minimum cut with a capacity that is a strict minimum for the graph (that is, flow could actually get backed up at the entrance to the cut).  See [max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) for details on flow networks and cuts.

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but if it isn't, you probably should provide a bit more information on that context.